# How do i untick the ticked cell when new cell ticked (exclusive uitableviewcell selection)(ios)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I tried this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

// this code im trying to toggle already ticked cell

    NSString *knownObject = @"YES";
    NSArray *alreadyTickedBoxes;
    //    NSInteger dictIndex= -1;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;

    for (dict in self.dataArray){
    //        dictIndex++;
         alreadyTickedBoxes = [dict allKeysForObject:knownObject];
        if (alreadyTickedBoxes.count !=0)
            break;
    }

    if(alreadyTickedBoxes.count != 0){

        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"checked"];
        FeedCell3 *cellToUntick = [dict objectForKey:@"cell"];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cellToUntick.accessoryView;
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked24"];
        [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }


// this code toggles tapped cell

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  ;
    BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];
    FeedCell3 *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked24"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticked24"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: have you try with `deselectRowAtIndexPath:` method of tableview rather than reloading tableview. ?

Comment: not yet no. thanks ill try that

Comment: ok Let me know if you get any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by just keeping a reference to the last selected index.

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate


- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.feedTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.feedTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.feedTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // initialise previous index path to current index path

    if(self.oldIndexPathRowIndex<0){
        self.oldIndexPathRowIndex = indexPath.row;
    }

    // the following code should toggle previously selected row

    if ( self.oldIndexPathRowIndex != indexPath.row) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dictAtOldIndex = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex: self.oldIndexPathRowIndex];
        BOOL checked = [[dictAtOldIndex objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
        NSString *text = [dictAtOldIndex objectForKey:@"text"] ;
        NSLog(@"Toggling previously tapped row: %@ checked: %d", text, checked);

        [dictAtOldIndex setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];
        checked = [[dictAtOldIndex objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
        NSLog(@"Previously tapped row: %@ toggled to: %d", text, checked);
        FeedCell3 *cellToUntick = [dictAtOldIndex objectForKey:@"cell"];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cellToUntick.accessoryView;
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked40x43"];
        [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //update current index path
        self.oldIndexPathRowIndex = indexPath.row;
    }


    // this code toggles currently tapped row

    NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  ;
    BOOL checked2 = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    NSString *text = [item valueForKey:@"text"];

    NSLog(@"Toggling currently tapped row: %@ checked: %d", text, checked2);


    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked2] forKey:@"checked"];
    checked2 = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
    NSLog(@"Currently tapped row: %@ toggled to: %d", text, checked2);
    FeedCell3 *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
    UIImage *newImage2 = (checked2) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unticked40x43"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"ticked40x43"];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage:newImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   // NSLog(@"Old Index Path is now row: %d", self.oldIndexPathRowIndex);
    [tableView reloadData];

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self tableView: self.feedTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    [self.feedTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


}
```